# How do I login a user using nuxt auth's loginWith() function?

Tags: express, vuex, nuxt-auth

I am creating an application that uses nuxt as frontend and an expressjs api as backend.
JWT token authentication is working in backend and I am now trying to register a user from the frontend and log him in using Nuxt auth's loginWith().

When I try to register a user, auth.loggedIn and auth.user are both equal to false. I don't understand what is going wrong as I'd expect auth.loggedIn to be true and auth.user to have the value returned by my '/api/me' api route.

##### nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.token' },
          user: { url: 'me', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.user'},
          logout: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

##### register.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <form method="post" @submit.prevent="register">
            <v-container fluid>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                        <v-text-field v-model="username" label="username" />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                        <v-text-field v-model="email" label="email" />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                        <v-text-field v-model="password" label="password" />
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                        <v-text-field v-model="matchPassword" label="password" />
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
            <v-btn type="submit">Register</v-btn>
        </form>
        <div style="margin-top: 20px">
            Already got an account ? <nuxt-link to="/login">Login</nuxt-link>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"registerComponent",
    data () {
        return {
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            matchPassword: '',
            error: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async register () {
            try {
                const registerReponse = await this.$axios.post('register', {
                    username: this.username,
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                })

                
                const loginResponse = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
                    data: {
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.password
                    },
                })

                console.log(registerReponse, loginResponse)

                // this.$router.push('/')
            } catch (e) {
                this.error = e.response.data.message
            }
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Here's the output of the console.log() above when registering a user :

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "User created "
    },
    "status": 201,
    "statusText": "Created",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "27",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "config": {
        "url": "register",
        "method": "post",
        "data": "{\"username\":\"oi\",\"email\":\"oiu@oiu.oiu\",\"password\":\"poiupoiu\"}",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "baseURL": "http://localhost:3002/api",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        }
    },
    "request": {}
},
{
    "data": {
        "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MjYsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6Im9pdSIsImlhdCI6MTY2NDk2MDc1NSwiZXhwIjoxNjY0OTcxNTU1fQ.goay796jUdmi-NYjSloDdeK6besuz8swJcMslDmklZU"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
        "content-length": "181",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "config": {
        "url": "login",
        "method": "post",
        "data": "{\"email\":\"oiu@oiu.oiu\",\"password\":\"poiupoiu\"}",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "baseURL": "http://localhost:3002/api",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "propertyName": "data.token"
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

#### Express app

You can see above the output of the /api/register and /api/login routes.

Here's the /api/me route (it just returns a hard-coded username for now) :

```
app.post('/api/me', authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
    client.query('SELECT user_name from user_account where id = $1', ['1'], (error, results) => {
        res.json( {user: { username: results.rows[0].user_name }} )
    })
})
```

### Edit

[image: Here's a screenshot of the vue devtool after attempting to register a user]

Here's a screenshot of the vue devtool after attempting to register a user

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue : I needed to set the token property in nuxt.config.js.

#### Nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'data.accessToken',
          global: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.token' },
          user: { url: 'me', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.user'},
          logout: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The 'user' state is now correctly set to the response from the backend and 'loggedIn' is set to True.